# PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a5547326/public_html/index.php on line 6

Tags: php

I have been trying to put up a small testing site for a project at [codebase.host22.org](http://codebase.host22.org), and I cant seem to get my PHP script to work. The script is hown as follows:

```
<?php

  $browser = get_browser(null, true);
  $data =  $browser[browser]

  $f = fopen("data.csv", "a");
  fwrite($f, $data = ",");
  fclose($f);

?>
```

I don't see a problem. But I get this error when trying to visit the page:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a5547326/public_html/index.php on line 6

My hosting is with 000webhost. Is there a problem with my code or the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed semicolon after $data variable.

```
$data =  $browser[browser];
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the quote and the semicolon:

`$data =  $browser['browser'];`